# konica minolta linux authentication

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, принтер, gentoo

Как можно настроить печать из Linux машины с использованием ppd драйвера Konica Minolta при включенной аутентификации на МФУ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нагуглил и оно работает: https://anykeyposts.blogspot.com/2018/08/konika-minolta-linux-authentication-pdd.html

Без этих настроек печать с аутентификацией не заработает.